# How to get write in spark and hive query for below case

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

My data is:

```
User id     product_id    action

1                apple             incart
1                 apple            purchased 
1                 banana         incart
2                 banana         incart
2                 banana         purchased
3                 carrot            incart
```

I need output as user_id and product_id whose action only has incart and not purchased.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. And show us your current code attempt.

Comment: I am beginner to spark and hive. I need an approach to this problem. The output should display user_id and product_id which has action = incart and not equal to purchased.

Comment: Do you have an RDD? A DF? Please try to be more specific and show us what you tried.

Comment: @pheeleeppoo using RDD or DF anything is fine. I only need approach to the problem. I know I need to use groupby on user_id and product_id, but how to find only those user_id and product_id which has record with action= incart and action != purchased

Comment: @RupeshMalkar Please check now

Answer (score 0):

```
val df1 = df.filter(col("action") === "purchased")
val df2 = df.filter(col("action") === "incart")
df2.join(df1,df2.col("User_id") === df1.col("User_id") && df2.col("product_id") === df1.col("product_id"),"leftanti").drop("action").show
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a DF like this:

```
+-------+----------+----------+
|User_id|product_id|    action|
+-------+----------+----------+
|      1|     apple|    incart|
|      1|     apple|purchased |
|      1|    banana|    incart|
|      2|    banana|    incart|
|      2|    banana| purchased|
|      3|    carrot|    incart|
+-------+----------+----------+
```

an approach could be apply a groupBy to create a new field containing all actions and then filter by your desired conditions.

```
val output = df.groupBy("User_id","product_id").agg(collect_list("action").as("set"))
```

Then filter on your desired condition. In this case:

```
output.where(array_contains($"set", "incart").and(!array_contains($"set", "purchased"))).select("User_id","product_id").show()
```

will produce the expected output:

```
+-------+----------+
|User_id|product_id|
+-------+----------+
|      3|    carrot|
|      1|    banana|
+-------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` in `HIVE`  :

```
SELECT t.userid, t.product_id 
FROM table t
WHERE action = 'incart' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM table t1 
                  WHERE t1.userid = t.userid and 
                        t1.product_id = t.product_id and 
                        t1.action = 'purchased'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using simple aggregation + `case`:

```
SELECT t.userid, t.product_id
FROM
(
SELECT t.userid, t.product_id, 
       max(case when t.action = 'purchased' then 1 else 0 end) has_purchased,
       max(case when t.action = 'incart'    then 1 else 0 end) has_incart
FROM table t
GROUP BY t.userid, t.product_id
) s
WHERE has_purchased=0 and has_incart=1;
```